# How to create a user without password in couchbase?

Tags: php, couchbase

In early version, couchbase has a default user which has no password.  I can use php memcache api to acces couchbase.

Now couchbase has no default user.  When I create a user, must input a password.  My old code can not run with it. I know php-couchbase-api can work with password. There are too many code, I do not want to change them.

Is there anyway to create a user without password?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said anything about why your old code "can't run with it".

I should think, though, that it would be trivial to use some canonical password, for all users...